# Blender Tree particle system

Tags: particles, hair

Hi I made a low poly tree with Branche particles as hair and want to set the trees with a particle system on a ground 
But if I set them with a particle system to the ground I can’t see my branches

Comment: I need to use displacement on the leaves threats why I want 2 particles systems

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, this should be a solution: the branch of the tree is one object and the leaves are one object. So if you set a particle system on the leavs, the leaves will be the only ones that get multiplied. You need to combine them to one object. (For example, Ctrl J) (If Yes, please write back so I can post it in the users tab - if not tell me as well so I can delete it)

Comment: If I join it to 1 object the leaves are going to deleted

Comment: you need to convert the tree branch from a curve to a mesh. Then it should work. You need to "rightclick" on the branch and select "convert to mesh". Then select both (branch and leavs) and then combine them to one object "Ctrl J"